# httpInterceptor response called several times for one response shown in network

Tags: angularjs, angular-http-interceptors

i am trying to use http interceptors in my angular app.
Now, i see in the console that one request is fired and successfully returns a response, but if i add a console log in the response part of the httpInterceptor, the console log is fired several times (~10 times).

I add the interceptor in the config part of my app like this:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpInterceptor');
```

I define it like this:

```
.factory('httpInterceptor', ['$q', '$rootScope', function ($q, $rootScope) {
        var numLoadings = 0;
        return {
            response: function (response) {
                console.log('response:', response);
                return response || $q.when(response);
            }
        };
    }]);
```

Comment: can you make a plunker?

Comment: quite a complex project. i'll try thou